# Javascript - updating textarea freezes browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, freeze

I am updating text in text area with javascript every 2 seconds, however sometimes happen that entire page freezes and you have to close the tab (other tabs in browser are working normally, this happens to all people visiting the page).

This is how my code looks like:

```
                function ajaxSyncRequest(reqURL) {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", reqURL, false);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xmlhttp.send('server=" + server + "');
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
                            document.getElementById(\"1\").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            if (document.getElementById('check').checked) { document.getElementById(\"1\").scrollTop = document.getElementById(\"1\").scrollHeight; }
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById(\"1\").innerHTML = "Could not connect to remote server!";\n
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And this is the 2 seconds timer:

```
                        function timer() {
                            ajaxSyncRequest("ConsoleGenerator");
                            window.setTimeout("timer()", 2000);
                        }
```

I am getting the text with POST method to Java Servlet. It works sometimes for hours and then it freezes and browser says "Page is not reposnding..." or sometimes it works just a few minutes and then it freezes...

Can anybody help please ?

Comment: Do you happen to have a working jsfiddle for this?

Comment: `document.getElementById(\"1\").innerHTML` Huh? What are those backslashes doing there? That's a syntax error.

Comment: And here: `"Could not connect to remote server!";\n` Please bother to take the time to post code without basic syntax errors. (Ideally *not* pointlessly indened 15+ characters, forcing half of it out of view.)

Comment: Thanks, the backslashes are there because this code is inside a String in java.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming we fix the basic syntax errors in the code.) You're happily firing off a subsequent requests without waiting for previous ones to complete. If the ajax call *ever* takes more than two seconds, you'll have overlapping calls. That isn't a problem in and of itself unless your backend is serializing calls or similar, but it does set up a chaotic situation.

You're also making *synchronous* requests by specifying `false` as the third argument to the POST call. There's no need to make the request synchronous, and doing so (particularly every **two seconds**?!) will indeed tend to lock up the UI of the browser.

I would recommend waiting for the previous request to complete before scheduling the next one, and making the requests asynchronous so the browser UI isn't locked:

```
// Accept callback --------------v
function ajaxSyncRequest(reqURL, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", reqURL, true);
    // async, not sync ----------^
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send('server=" + server + "');
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
                document.getElementById("1").scrollTop = document.getElementById("1").scrollHeight;
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Could not connect to remote server!\n";
        }
        callback(); // <== Call it
    }
}

function timer() {
    ajaxSyncRequest("ConsoleGenerator", function() { // Pass in a callback
        setTimeout(timer, 2000);
    });
}
```

That will wait for the ajax to complete and then schedule another update two seconds later. If you want to include the time the ajax call took in the two seconds instead, we can do some basic math:

```
function timer() {
    var started = Date.now();
    ajaxSyncRequest("ConsoleGenerator", function() { // Pass in a callback
        setTimeout(timer, Max.max(0, 2000 - (Date.now() - started));
    });
}
```

---

Side note: No need for the `window.` prefix on `setTimeout` (though it's harmless provided nothing's shadowed the global `window`), and rather than passing a string to it, just pass a function reference.

Comment: every decent browser will warn that _synchronous xmlhttprequest is deprecated on the main thread_ - that's a warning that you may want to rewrite your code to NOT use synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Wow, I didn't even notice that `false` at the end. Agreed, absolutely should be async.

Comment: Thanks, the backslashes are there because this code is inside a String in java. I will try it.

Comment: I am not sure what went wrong, but as I replaced my code with yours it stopped working completely, I just get blank text area.

Comment: I found the issue, whenever I set the parametr (async) to true it stops working.